# Creating graph using igraph in R

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, igraph

I have data frame (df) with 2 columns like:

```
Project:      Person: 
1            a            
1            b              
1            c           
1            d
2            c
2            a
..sample data..
```

I want to make a graph using `igraph package`, which will show connections between People working on Projects. My desired output should look similar to that:
[image]

Should I transform my data somehow to make that graph, or current form is ok?

Comment: Your sample data would not make that graph. Your graph makes it look like projects 1 and 2 share one staff member, but your data has `a` and `c` in both projects 1 and 2.  Did you want the last line of your data to say something like `2  e` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe of edges, like your example `df`, then you can use `igraph::graph_from_data_frame` to generate this with minimal reshaping of your data. For example:

```
> df <- data.frame(project=c(1,1,1,1,2,2), person=c("a","b","c","d","c","a"))
> g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
> plot(g)
```

[Plotted graph g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVXHw.png)